# TypeORM error when trying to create migration in CLI

Tags: javascript, typescript, yarnpkg, typeorm

I'm trying to use the TypeORM CLI to create a migration. I followed their guide but when I run `yarn run typeorm migration:generate` I get the error:

```
$ typeorm-ts-node-commonjs migration:generate
/usr/bin/env: ‘node --require ts-node/register’: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: use -[v]S to pass options in shebang lines
error Command failed with exit code 127.
```

My package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "watch": "tsc -w",
    "start": "node dist/index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon dist/index.js",
    "start2": "ts-node src/index.ts",
    "dev2": "nodemon --exec ts-node src/index.ts",
    "typeorm": "typeorm-ts-node-commonjs"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "apollo-server-express": "^3.6.7",
    "class-validator": "^0.13.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.3",
    "express-graphql": "^0.12.0",
    "graphql": "^15.3.0",
    "pg": "^8.7.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "ts-node": "^10.7.0",
    "type-graphql": "^1.1.1",
    "typeorm": "^0.3.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.23",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I managed to solve this by installing the cli as described here https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/using-cli#installing-cli

Install ts-node globally `npm install -g ts-node`

add the following script to package.json: `"typeorm": "node --require ts-node/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js"` instead of `"typeorm": "typeorm-ts-node-commonjs"`

then create a migration with:
`yarn run typeorm migration:generate -p -d src/data-source.ts src/migrations/<filename without ending>`

FYI For anyone facing similar issues: It took me a while to figure out that the various documentations on typeorm are confusing and conflicting at the moment because they just moved to v0.3.0 and not everything has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try use this version of the script
`"typeorm": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js"` in my case this work!